# Observable RX- Retrofit get data only first time

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, observable, retrofit2

This is a really strange issue that i have.

I'm using RX JAVA Observable with retrofit to get data from the server, these kind of data should change every time but it seems to load data only the first time and the rest o the time re-get the same data.

Also without INTERNET CONNECTION is still getting data (apparently from local) and still going into the onNext and not onError as should be.

This is my observable:

```
Token token = new Token(AppConfig.TOKEN_NEWS);
    Observable<ArrayList<NewsV0>> newsList = mZappAppApis.getNews(token.getToken());
    newsList
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<ArrayList<NewsV0>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Logger.i("Retriving user data onCompleted");
                    onLoadCompleted(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    Logger.e("Error retriving user data [" + e.getMessage() + "]");
                    onLoadCompleted(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ArrayList<NewsV0> newsV0s) {
                    Logger.i("Get news from api size ["+newsV0s.size()+"]");


                    //Every time go here, with internet and without internet, loading the same data
                }
            });
```

My retrofit api:

```
@GET("/News")
Observable<ArrayList<NewsV0>> getNews(
        @Header("Authorization") String authorization
);
```

I hope someone could help me!

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT:

This is the way i'm providing the RetrofitAdapter

```
@Provides
ZappAppApis provideContentApi(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    String apiUrl;

    apiUrl = AppConfig.protocolHttp + AppConfig.ZAPPAPP_API_BASE_URL;

    Logger.d("Base url API [ " + apiUrl + " ]");

    Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl(apiUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

    return restAdapter.create(ZappAppApis.class);
}
```

And this is the way i'm providing the OkHttpClient:

```
@Provides
OkHttpClient okHttpClient() {
    final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    else
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);

    // set disk cache
    client.setCache(new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), DISK_CACHE_SIZE));

    List<Interceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
    interceptors.add(loggingInterceptor);
    interceptors.add(new LoggingInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Key", AppConfig.ZAPPAPP_CLIENT_KEY)
                    .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=60")
                    .method(original.method(), original.body())
                    .build();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    client.networkInterceptors().addAll(interceptors);

    return client;
}
```

Comment: Are you doing any HTTP caching? Please post the code that you use to create the RestAdapter and instantiate your API client.

Comment: Yes, there is some caching but i don't think the problem is that.. thanks for the help (edited)

Comment: client.setCache(new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), DISK_CACHE_SIZE)); You are caching your results.

Comment: I've already tryed to remove this line but seems is not working anyway.. I'll re-try to night just to double check, if you have any other idea.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data when offline is coming from the HTTP cache.

Here you are creating the cache:

```
// set disk cache
client.setCache(new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), DISK_CACHE_SIZE));
```

and here you are adding a caching header to every request:

```
interceptors.add(new LoggingInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        Request request = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Key", AppConfig.ZAPPAPP_CLIENT_KEY)
                .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=60")
                .method(original.method(), original.body())
                .build();

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});
```

You can remove `.header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=60")` if the caching is not coming from the server. If caching is coming from the server you can use `.header("Cache-Control", "max-stale=0")` instead and it should get rid of the caching.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you explain me how to handle the cache on the client?